# App Approval for SMS and Call log Permission

Tags: android, google-apps, google-people-api

I All, I have created a very simple app for Auto SMS reply. The main objective of this application is to automatically send back a SMS when someone is unavailable to read or respond to that SMS.

The main issue is that It's not getting approved on Google Play Store as it is not fall under their policy.

I have implemented the disclosure form or activity about SMS permissions also that user without using granting that permission not able use that app. Added the privacy policy also that it's collecting or transferring any information to third party.

Can someone help me on this? How can I get approval for this android app on Google Play Store? Under which category I can put my app for approval?

Thanks,
Gaurav Kapoor

Comment: Any luck? Have you been able to make in Device Automation Exception?

Comment: No Luck, Still the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Google restricts the usage of the SMS permissions group to either the default SMS app or the one of permitted use-cases.

You can check the list of permitted use-cases here:
https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/10208820?hl=en

When you submit an app to Google Play that requests the user for the SMS permission, you must fill out a form in Google Play Console with the specific use-case your app is using, or else it'll be automatically denied.

From your explanation of the app's purpose it might go under 2 permitted use-cases: `Device automation` or `In-vehicle hands-free use`, but you probably know best which one to choose.

Then, it will be up to the Google reviewer that will check your app to decide whether or not your app's use-case is indeed what you claim it to be and is permitted to use SMS.

Comment: Thanks You for replying. but in both the cases it got rejected.